# Sequelize Model Relationship

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 models here -

**user.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataType) => {

  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataType.INTEGER
    },
    username: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        len:
          { args: [4, 20], msg: "Username should be contain 4-20 characters." },
        isAlphanumeric:
          { msg: "Only letters and numbers are allowed" }
      }
    },
    email: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail:
          { msg: "Provide proper email" }
      }
    },
    password: DataType.STRING,
    emailverified: DataType.BOOLEAN
  });

  User.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
```

**userprofile.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var userprofile = sequelize.define('userprofile', {
    nickName: DataTypes.STRING,
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    middleName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    gender: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    age: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    country: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    steamUrl: DataTypes.STRING,
    city: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    status: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  userprofile.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return userprofile;
};
```

Can someone give an example on how to set 1: N relationship from **user** to **userprofile** i.e, 1 **user** can have N number of **userprofiles** and also by creating this relationship will a record be auto-generated under **userprofiles** table whenever a **user** is created?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some research - 
ref: https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/user.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataType) => {

  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataType.INTEGER
    },
    username: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        len:
          { args: [4, 20], msg: "Username should be contain 4-20 characters." },
        isAlphanumeric:
          { msg: "Only letters and numbers are allowed" }
      }
    },
    email: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail:
          { msg: "Provide proper email" }
      }
    },
    password: DataType.STRING,
    emailverified: DataType.BOOLEAN
  });

  User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.userprofile, {
      foreignKey: 'userid',
    });
  };
```

The above code creates a foreign key in userprofile table and auto-generation is not done.